# Returning IEnumerable when the object is an IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ienumerable, iqueryable

I'm a bit confused about IEnumerable and `IQueryable` and interswapping of usages with Entity Framework.  I've tried to do as much googling as I can on the subject but it hasn't seemed to help.  So here's my situation.

I have a function(`MyClass` is an `EntityObject`):

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> GetMyClasses(int id) {
    return GetQuery().Where(p => p.Id==id);
}

IQueryable<MyClass> GetQuery() {
    // returns an IQueryable list here
}
```

Now my question is. Given I'm returning an IEnumerable here rather than an `IQueryable`, when the statement is executed with a **ToList()** will the underlying SQL generated take into account the `Id == id` statement and so only return filter items or will it bring all the objects of the database into memory and perform the Where clause on that list?

Any helps, or even pointers to resources that describe this?

Comment: This is up to the implementation of the IQueryable returned by EF, so the correct answer will be specific to the EF implementation. I would be that the `Where` is applied to the query, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the statement is executed with a **ToList()** will the underlying SQL generated take into account the Id == id statement and so only return filter items

The short answer is 'Yes'.

There is only `Enumerable.ToList<T>(this IEnumumerable<T> e)` and no counterpart for `IQueryable<T>`

Everything inside `GetMyClasses` method will be operated as `IQueryable<T>`, but the restrictions added after will be in-memory.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> GetMyClasses(int id) {
    return GetQuery().Where(p => p.Id==id); // this always will work as IQueryable and handled by provider (in case of EF - the DB query will be performed)
}

IEnumerable<MyClass> MoreRestrictions(int id) {
     return GetMyClasses(id)
         .ToList(); // result list will be filtered by Id
}

IEnumerable<MyClass> MoreRestrictions(int id) {
     return GetMyClasses(id)
         .Where(x=>x.IsActive) // this where will be performed in memory on results filtered by Id.
         .ToList(); 
}
```

Methods `ToList` and `Where` is works like following

```
//There is only one implementation of ToList()
public List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e) 
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    var enumerator = e.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var item = e.Current;
        list.Add(item);
    }
    return list;
}

//Implementation for IEnumerable
public IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Predicate predicate) 
{
    var enumerator = e.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var item = e.Current;
        if (predicate(item))
            yield return item;
    }
}

//Implementation for IQueryable
public IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> e, Expression<Predicate> predicate) 
{
    MethodBase method = ...; // create generic method of Queryable.Where()
    return e.Provider
        .CreateQuery<T>(Expression.Call(null, method, e.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate)));
}
```

The `GetEnumerator` method of IQueryable does query materialization.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was hoping for.  Just for clarification, can you explain why your second MoreRestrictions example will do some of the query as a SQL statement and some as in memory?

Comment: @dreza there two reasons for it: it will be restriction with pre-compiled predicate, not expression-based. The implementation of `Where` which accepts IEnumerable does not care about IQueryable and do filtering in memory.

Comment: I think that makes sense.  Seems to contradict Johns answer below though so am not 100%??.  Will look into the Where clauses you mentioned above a bit more.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You're making this too complicated. Consider the following:

```
public class Base { }

public class Derived : Base { }

public Base Method() {
    return GetOtherMethod();
}

public Derived GetOtherMethod()
{
    return new Derived ();
}
```

You're wondering about the characteristics of the return value from `Method`. It will be an instance of `Derived`, but you will only be able to use it as a `Base` unless you cast it to `Derived`.

So, your `GetMyClasses` will be returning an `IQueryable<MyClass>` that will be usable only as an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`.

Comment: So when the ToList() occurs on the IEnumerable will the resultant SQL include a Where id == 5 or will that occur in memory?

Comment: It's not an IEnumerable. It's an IQueryable which only has IEnumerable members available. It will behave like an IQueryable because that's what it is.

Comment: Ok thanks. Based on that in the case of hazziks answer in his 2nd MoreRestrictions() example I would have thought then that the returned results would all be converted to SQL given my type is actually an Queryable object??

Comment: There is no  magic here. Would such a conversion occur with my sample `Base` and `Derived` classes? No. Then it won't happen here. This is a simple case of polymorphism. The `GetEnumerator()` method of the returned `IQueryable` will implement the standard `IQueryable` semantics, even if the `GetEnumerator()` method is being referenced as `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: Ok, in my small world, your answer seems to contradict hazziks.  But maybe they are both saying the same thing and I'm just not getting it.  Thanks for your help in clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

This article is helpful:
[IQueryable vs IEnumerable in LINQ-to-SQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20120401112218/http://www.hamishgraham.net/post/RE-IQueryable-vs-IEnumerable-in-LINQ-to-SQL-queries.aspx).

Quoting that article, 'As per the MSDN documentation, calls made on IQueryable operate by building up the internal expression tree instead.
"These methods that extend IQueryable(Of T) do not perform any querying directly. Instead, their functionality is to build an Expression object, which is an expression tree that represents the cumulative query. "'

Expression trees are a very important construct in C# and on the .NET platform. (They are important in general, but C# makes them very useful.) To better understand the difference, I recommend reading about the differences between *expressions* and *statements* [in the official C# 5.0 specification here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) For advanced theoretical concepts that branch into lambda calculus, expressions enable support for methods as first-class objects. The difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable is centered around this point. IQueryable builds expression trees whereas IEnumerable does not, at least not in general terms for those of us who don't work in the secret labs of Microsoft.

Here is another very useful article that details the differences from a push vs. pull perspective. (By "push" vs. "pull," I am referring to direction of data flow. [Reactive Programming Techniques for .NET and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646361/Reactive-Programming-for-NET-and-Csharp-Developers)

Here is a very good article that details the differences between statement lambdas and expression lambdas and discusses the concepts of expression tress in greater depth: [Revisiting C# delegates, expression trees, and lambda statements vs. lambda expressions.](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/09/revisiting-few-c-concepts-delegates.html).